# Issue when running a newly created project in siteinfinity 4.4 project manager

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity-4

I am facing an issue when running a newly created project in siteinfinity 4.4 project manager :

**Issue log :**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,      PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the  file specified.
Stack trace:
   at Telerik.Utilities.Cassini.Server.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Start>b__1(Object )
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext,   ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at  System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWork Item()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Any idea will be appreciated?

Comment if any detail is required.

Comment: are you getting this when creating a project with the project manager, or when trying to run it using the project manager? can you run it as a website in visual studio? Do you have asp.net installed and registered on the machine?

Comment: Appears when trying to run a project using the project manager, asp.net 4.0 is installed, didn't tried visual studio, but it should run from the project manager.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the full asp.net installed and registered? Even though it is self-contained, I believe that Cassini still requires that the full framework be installed to run.